# How to read all columns from Avro when newer partitions have more columns then older ones?

Tags: apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I've got data in Avro format partitioned by date and time and I receiving new data every hour. Newer partitions can contain more columns then older ones. When I read it by Spark 2.4.3 I got DataFrame with schema of the first(oldest) partition and all newer added columns are lost. 
What should I do to read all columns? Is there some workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add a snipped of your code?

Comment: Here it is =)
sparkSession.read
      .format("avro")
      .load(pathToData)

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is the ability to merge the schema of the different files Spark reads. You can achieve this with the `mergeSchema` option. This capability applies to all file-based data sources, not just Avro.

`sparkSession.read.format("avro").option("mergeSchema", true).load(pathToData)`